# Remove elements from an list in a python file

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
array = ['info@aireconsultores.es','integralfitstore@gmail.com','info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com']
```

and then I have a text file with the following:

```
info@aireconsultores.es
integralfitstore@gmail.com
info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com
ertsol1@lubrial2000.com
contact@ytcvn.com
info@centroro.es
```

How could I remove the elements in the text file from my list, that is, so that the file looks like this:

```
ertsol1@lubrial2000.com
contact@ytcvn.com
info@centroro.es
```

Comment: Your description is a little confusing.  Are you removing strings from the list, or from the file?  In either case, I'd suggest loading the text file into a list.  Then you can compare and/or iterate through two lists.  If you want a new file, write the appropriate list to a file.

Comment: Why would removing items from the _list_ make the _file_ look different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the lines, I would create a new file, with the entries removed, something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as in_file, open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.strip() not in array:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
def func(emails_to_exclude):
    with open('test.txt') as fr, open('test_2.txt', 'w') as fw:
        for line in fr:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                if line not in emails_to_exclude:
                    fw.write('{}\n'.format(line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        'info@aireconsultores.es',
        'integralfitstore@gmail.com',
        'info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com',
    ]
    func(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an array into a set (let's call it s1), also read the data from the source file into a set (let's call it s2).  the difference between these sets is the desired result, i.e.  result = s2.difference (s1))

```
array = ['info@aireconsultores.es', 'integralfitstore@gmail.com', 'info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com']

with open('data.txt', 'r') as src:
    src_data = set(map(str.strip, src.readlines()))

with open('out.txt', 'w') as dst:
    dst.write("\n".join(src_data.difference(set(array))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you have the six emails in a list and the three emails you want to exclude in a list named `array`. You can use `numpy` to exclude these three emails:

```
import numpy as np
my_list = np.array(["info@aireconsultores.es","integralfitstore@gmail.com","info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com","ertsol1@lubrial2000.com","contact@ytcvn.com","info@centroro.es"])
my_array = ['info@aireconsultores.es','integralfitstore@gmail.com','info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com']
my_list[~np.isin(my_list, my_array)]
```

However, if you have the list of six emails in a `.txt` file, then I suggest you read the file as a pandas data frame and then exclude the mails in the list named `array`.:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./file.txt", header=None, names=["email"])
my_array = ['info@aireconsultores.es','integralfitstore@gmail.com','info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com']
df = df[~df["email"].isin(my_array)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("new.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("new.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines: 
      if (line.strip("\n") != "ertsol1@lubrial2000.com" and line.strip("\n") != "contact@ytcvn.com" and line.strip("\n") != "info@centroro.es"): 
        f.write(line)
```